# d3.js load more data quicker

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

I used some d3 example code and managed to make a parallel coordinates plot with my own data. I've made it here:

http://bl.ocks.org/jimshady/603c93b159a3060858ad

However when I increase the amount of data (I want to have about 45,000 rows of data), it is very unresponsive and slow to load.

I wonder if someone could advise/help me on how to improve this please?

Comment: use pagination showing chunks of 1000 at a button click, of if you want to have all in place use lazy loading in chunks of 1000 with a loader on top. Usually is recommended to have less http calls and as much as possible large objects, but when browser fails to interpret gargantuan sizes you can split requests, to give browser time to breath.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas SilentTremor. Do you have some example code that I could incorporate into my webpage please? I'm not very familiar with what you are talking about.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I have just been given a folder that I map to on our webserver. I can ask our IT person? http://www.londonair.org.uk/research/lhem_dose_v2/

Comment: It's a IIS possible .net, now idk if that is really a file or a handler. If it's indeed a file well you will have a lot to work in it. Check a bit this article: http://www.coppelia.io/2013/01/lazy-d3-on-some-astronomical-data/ and another approach in response of this

Comment: It's a file. A large CSV file. I'm not sure how that link helps? I've just read it all, but nothing about working with large CSV files in D3?